# How to Flip a view (with UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal) inside UINavigationController and UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, flip

I've an App with UITabBarController and UINavigationController, I would like to make a View to flip (with UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal) when I push an UIBarButtonItem

as I'm doing now, when I push the button **all** the screen flips, but what I want is to flip just the "content" and not the navigationController and the tabBarController, cause in the flipped view they disappear!!

How should I do?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ok! I've made it!

I've followed this example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: The code that you are pointing to does everything in code.  Did you do the same?  Or did you use any xibs?